# How sensitive is the primary key stub of an ed25519 security key (~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk)?

Tags: ecc, yubikey, openssh, fido, ecdsa

Now that OpenSSH supports Elliptic curve security keys (since version 8.2), it's possible to generate a `ed25519-sk` key on a hardware security key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C comment
```

This generates a public and a private key parts. **How sensitive is the private part** that goes into file `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk`?

As it seems it's required for the ability to use the security key on another machine, so I assume it's necessary to distribute it to all client machines usable with the key or store on some removable medium. Does it pose a security risk, or is the private file simply useless without the hardware key?

And somewhat related question: Does this process overwrite the key stored on the hardware, that is, is it possible to have only one such SSH key for each hardware key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "FIDO/U2F Support" section in [OpenSSH 8.2 Release Notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2)

> The private key file
> should be useless to an attacker who does not have access to the
> physical token.