# Is it possible to regenerate the stub private key from just the physical key in OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, key-management, key-generation, yubikey, openssh

Let's say I make an id of type `ed25519-sk` and have it reside on my yubikey. OpenSSH makes two files, `id_ed25519_sk`, a stub private key, and `id_ed25519_sk.pub` the corresponding public key.

If I lose these, can I regenerate them with just the external physical key?

Comment: Related to (but not a duplicate of) [How sensitive is the primary key stub of an ed25519 security key (~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258509/42391)